# How to hide and show images drawn on canvas on event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 3d, 2d

I drawn images on Canvas by passing x and y co-ordinates from JSON.
But I want to hide those images if I checked the checkbox button and want to show if I un-checked the checkbox button.

So will appreciate if any hints.

Comment: You need to redraw the canvas without drawing the images you want to hide

Comment: please provide code for better answers

Comment: @Ray'user1578904' : Above question is updated with source code

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can hide show your image div following is the way you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#map_canvas").hide();
    $("#map_checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($("#map_checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $("#map_canvas").show();
        } else if ($("#map_checkbox").not(":checked")) {
            $("#map_canvas").hide();
        }
    })
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p3WFE/)

**Note:** in the above code **#map_canvas** is your canvas div with attribute id=map_canvas. and **#map_checkbox** is checkbox with attribute id=#map_checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledge, your answer is very good for the image which is inside the div. But in my source images are plotted on canvas from JSON. In that case what can be done?

Comment: @eegloo great hope this answer will help to others.